# How to implement middle mouse button click on commandButtons in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

The middle click seems not to work for `commandButton` in JSF. At least not as expected - which would be opening the result of the action in a new tab. No submit/action is triggered.

The mouseup and mousedown events seem to work OK as the "animation" for a pressed button is working on middle click.

Middle clicks on `commandLink` work as expected.

How would I go about implementing a "normal" middle click behaviour for my `commandButtons`? How would i know on the mouseup/down events which button has been clicked?

Thank you.

I am using JSF 2 with Mojarra 2.1.7

Comment: Opening a url in new tab and submitting a form which belongs to current page in new tab are completely different things. Consider your username in this page. Middle-Click it and expected behavior is navigation to your profile. What is the expected behavior when you Middle-Click "POST YOUR ANSWER" button at the bottom of this page?

Comment: I would expect the current page to remain unchanged with the usual post-response behaviour occuring in the new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no "normal" middleclick behaviour. This is unspecified in HTML and the default behaviour is browser dependent.

As to the concrete question, you could catch it in the `onclick` event. On a middle click the `event.which` would return `2`. You can then set the form's target to `_blank` to let it submit to a new window.

```
 onclick="if (event.which == 2) form.target = '_blank'"
```

Again, this will not work for some browsers.

Comment: Worked with Chromium 18, didn't with FF 11. I didn't know the behaviour was browser-dependent, so I will refrain from using your solution. Many thanks anyway, BalusC.